# Episerver Forms retrieve submitted records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, episerver

In episerver CMS, I have installed Alloy sample site, "Episerver.forms" and then created a form. On the view mode, I have browsed the form and submitted the form after entering the values. I could see the list of submitted records, when I click “Form submissions” on the editor page. I need to show those submitted records on a page. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

This is done by using the `IFormDataRepository`

Dejan explained it here https://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/-Episerver-75-CMS/Thread-Container/2017/5/programetically-getting-episerver--forms--submitted-data/

```
List<Submission> submittedData = _formDataRepository.GetSubmissionData(
    new FormIdentity(formGuid, languageBranch),
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100),
    DateTime.Now).ToList();
```