# Show submitted form records on page in Episerver

Tags: episerver, episerver-forms

I have created a form and submitted, but I would like to show these records on an Episerver page.

I tried but it is not working.

[Screenshot of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzkU5.jpg)

[Screenshot of submitted records in edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hstmr.jpg)

Comment: Have a look at `IFormRepository` as a starting point for retrieving forms and form data.

Comment: Please include some code demonstrating what you've tried so far.

Comment: Also, check out duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49107171/episerver-forms-retrieve-submitted-records