# Episerver Forms submitted data print on page

Tags: episerver, episerver-forms

I have created Episerver form: [screenshot of rendered form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQJlP.jpg)

I can see submitted records: [screenshot of form records in edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZPZc.jpg)

I would like to print the records on the page but I don't know how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Episerver: I need to show submitted form records on page in episerver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70390508/episerver-i-need-to-show-submitted-form-records-on-page-in-episerver)

Comment: Hi Ted Nyberg,

I tried with IFormRepository but it is not working.

Comment: Since you already have a question on this topic, I think you should add some code to it to demonstrate what you've tried so far: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70390508/episerver-i-need-to-show-submitted-form-records-on-page-in-episerver

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.